# Should ngModelChange work with custom form control?

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say I'm making a custom form control. Can I do this?

```
<custom-control [ngModel]="myModelVariable" (ngModelChange)="modelHasChanged($event)"></custom-control>
```

I'm able to get [(ngModel)] working with all the form controls I've made, but I'm not able to check for changes. A lot of people using my components need this, and I'm wondering if there is a clean way to do it without creating @Output EventEmitters. I'm thinking I'm not doing something correctly, but maybe I'm wrong.

This is a sample component implementation following the pattern I understand:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-control',
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useClass: CustomControlComponent, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class CustomControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = (_: any) => {};
  private onTouchedCallback: () => void = () => {};

  private innerValue: any;

  get value(): any {
    return this.innerValue;
  }

  set value(val: any) {
    if (val !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = val;
      this.onChangeCallback(this.innerValue);
    }
  }

  writeValue(val: any) {
    if (val !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = val;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

}
```

Comment: If `[(ngModel)]="xxx"` works, `(ngModelChange)="xxx = $event"` will work as well. I don't see what might cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After closer inspection, some of the components in question weren't calling the onChangedCallback in the setter, hence our problems. Others weren't being implemented correctly.

Sorry for bothering you, Angular world.